# Reset Multiple Input Fields to data-original-value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to reset all the input fields to their original values that are stored in a data-original-value attribute.  The issues is I am tripping up on using "$this".  Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/deDdy/29/

Code:

```
<div id="test">
 <input type="text" value="320" data-original-value="320">
 <input type="text" value="420" data-original-value="420">
 <textarea maxlength="1000" rows="8" data-original-value="hi all">hi all</textarea>
 <select data-original-value="Op1">
   <option value="Op1">Op1</option>
   <option value="Op2">Op2</option>
 </select>    
 <a href="#" class="restore">Restore</a>
</div>

 $(document).on("click", ".restore", function(){
  $('test').children().find('input,select,textarea').each(function(){
  $(this).val($(this).data("original-value"));
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like jaunt's answer of using a reset button and letting the form reset automatically however if the constraint of your project require for you to use the data attributes then I would use the attributes selector to select any of the items with [data-original-value] then loop thru each item using $.each

```
$('.restore').click(function(e){
    $('[data-original-value]').each(function(){
        $(this).val($(this).data('original-value'));
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jdn0ptf9/

Answer (score 4):

Why do you need jQuery for this? 
Seems a bit of a waste of good HTML attributes...

```html
<form id="test">
  <input type="text" value="320">
  <input type="text" value="420">
  <textarea maxlength="1000" rows="8">Hi all</textarea>
  <select>
    <option selected>Op1</option>
    <option>Op2</option>
  </select>
  <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on("click", ".restore", function() {
    $('#test').children('input, select, textarea').each(function() {
        var el = $(this);
        el.val(el.data("original-value"));
    });
});
```

[Working demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/deDdy/32/)

Comment: Oh my god I forgot the # hahaha.  I don't always screw up, but when I do I make it epic.